# Efficiency of extracting a bit from byte

Tags: c++, c, bit-manipulation, bitset

I'm extracting the 8th bit from a byte in C. Here is my example.

```
register unsigned char byte;

int pos = 7;

int x =(byte >> pos) & 1;   //Method I

int y =(byte & 0x80) >> pos;    //Method II
```

Both techniques will result in the same output, but is one of the methods more efficient than the other?

Comment: method 2 won't work if pos has a different value

Comment: If performance of the operation is critical for you, then you'll need to check the assembly that the compiler is generating and also benchmark it.

Comment: They are the same but you could optimize it for specific instruction sets by going down to assembly and using the jump if zero/jump if carry instructions...

Comment: @nonsensical not sure what you are talking about, but anything using a jump/conditional is not going to be as fast as simple bit manipulation

Comment: @Keith Nicholas I'm talking about just doing the `(byte & 0x80)` operation and using the Zero flag in the status register to determine it it is a 1 or a 0... On ARM you can attach this condition to the instruction itself turning it into a one instruction operation. http://www.davespace.co.uk/arm/introduction-to-arm/conditional.html

Answer (score 4):

Both will be the same. Both AND and SHR instructions are 1-clock instructions on intel CPUs.

Comment: Good point. I think irrespective of bit value (one or zero) in a byte the cpu is going to perform AND-ing of all the bits.

Answer (score 1):

Bitwise operations a basically one of the fastest things you'll find on a computer. I'd imagine that any difference would be *incredibly* minor, such that it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the bit you are extracting at compile-time, then either method should have approximately the same speed:

```
unsigned char val;
const int pos = 4;
...
int x = (val >> pos) & 1;
int y = (val & 0x10) >> pos;
```

However if you are calculating the position at runtime and not as a constant, doing the AND last should be faster:

```
unsigned char val;
int pos;
...
/* requires only a shift and AND */
int x = (val >> pos) & 1;
/* requires two shifts and AND */
int y = (val & (1 << pos)) >> pos;
```